# How to increase the saturation values of an image using HSV (in OpenCV using C++)?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019, photo

I was looking for a way to increase the saturation of some of my images using code and found the strategy of splitting a material with HSV and then increasing the S channel by a factor. However, I ran into some issues where the split channels were still in BGR (I think) because the output was just a greener tinted version of the original.

```
    //Save original image to material
    Mat orgImg = imread("sunset.jpg");
    //Resize the image to be smaller
    resize(orgImg, orgImg, Size(500, 500));
    //Display the original image for comparison
    imshow("Original Image", orgImg);
    
    Mat g = Mat::zeros(Size(orgImg.cols, orgImg.rows), CV_8UC1);

    Mat convertedHSV;
    orgImg.convertTo(convertedHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat saturatedImg;
    
    Mat HSVChannels[3];
    split(convertedHSV, HSVChannels);

    imshow("H", HSVChannels[0]);
    imshow("S", HSVChannels[1]);
    imshow("V", HSVChannels[2]);

    HSVChannels[1] *= saturation;
    merge(HSVChannels, 3, saturatedImg);

    //Saturate the original image and save it to a new material.
    
    //Display the new, saturated image.
    imshow("Saturated", saturatedImg);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

This is my code and nothing I do makes it actually edit the saturation, all the outputs are just green tinted photos.
*Note* saturation is a public double that is usually set to around 1.5 or whatever you want.

Comment: Curious, for me it works, but only with saturation > 1.0. Otherwise the output is *pink*. Multiplication seems to work, judging by looking at single pixel.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]. your debugging should have involved inspecting intermediate results, and narrowing the issue down to the `convertTo` result looking different from what you expect. -- your entire code also never contains an attempt to convert back from HSV to BGR... the apparent lack of need for that is suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `cv::convertTo()` here. [It changes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) the **bitdepth** (and representation, `int` vs. `float`) of the image, **not** what you are trying to achieve, the **color space**.

Using it like that does not throw a warning or error though, because both type indicators (`CV_8U`, ...) and the colorspace indicators (`COLOR_BGR2HSV`,...) can be resolved as integers, one is a #define, the other a old style enum.

Following the example [here](https://anishdubey.com/desaturation-filter-image-opencv), it is possible to do with `cv::cvtColor()`. Don't forget to revert back before showing the image, `imshow()` and `imwrite()` both expect an BGR format.

```
// Convert image from BGR -> HSV:
// orgImg.convertTo(convertedHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); // <- this wrong, do not use
cvtColor(orgImg, convertedHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); // <- this does the trick instead

// to the split, multiplication, merge
// [...]


// Convert image back HSV -> BGR:
cvtColor(saturatedImg, saturatedImg, COLOR_HSV2BGR);

//Display the new, saturated image.
imshow("Saturated", saturatedImg);
```

Note that oCV does not care about color representation when working with a 3 channel `Mat`: Could be RGB, HSV or anything else. Only for displaying (or saving to an image format) does the given color space matter.

Comment: Hey sorry for the really delayed response. Implemented your answer last year and it works great! Thank you so much, was stuck for a while! Appreciate the comment explanations in your example as well.